# Call a file outside of the directory from inside of a directory - Python

Tags: python

I have a directory which has all the files:

```
myDirectory/
    directory1/
        importantFile.py
    Output.py
```

How can I import Output.py from importantFile.py without having to put in the same directory?

importantFile.py

```
import Output
Output.write('This worked!')
```

Output.py

```
class Output():
    def writeOutput(s):
        print s
```

Comment: Could I have an example?

Comment: please define what you mean by "call", is it import ? I'd provide a small content for Output and ImportantFile explaining what you want to do

Comment: By call, do you mean import? Or `subprocess.call()`?

Comment: Use relative path "../Output.py"

Comment: By call I mean import.

Answer (score 1):

if "call" is import, in Output.py

```
import sys
import os.path
# change how import path is resolved by adding the subdirectory
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()+'/directory1'))
import importantFile

importantFile.f()
```

`sys.path` contains the list of path where to look for modules, details in https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use the relative notation, for which the python file you want to import should be in a package.

You have to make the directory a python package by putting an **init**.py file.

Look for the packages section in this link.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/full/path/to/use')
global exist_importedname
exist_importedname = True
try:
    import myimport
except ImportError as e:
    exist_importedname = False
    print (e.message)
```